# Speaker OUT To MIC IN

Tags: arduino, dfplayer

I want to use dfplayer modules speaker output to connect to SIM800L MIC IN Pins.
Can this being done? How to connect it?
In other words Instead of a MIC input on SIM800L module, I use the sound out of the dfplayer module.
Please see the attached file.

What is the reason for the noise? How can I fix the noise? Can you guide me by schematic?

[image]

I tested the following items according to the picture, but there is still noise
[image]
[image]

[image]